# pointer problems when trying to build a directory tree in memory

Tags: c, linux, unix, tree

Problem 1: what's the best data structure to save the directory structure?

Problem 2: I have tried to use a general tree to solve it, but there are a lot of problems:

- The number of files under a directory is not certain. So the number of child nodes under a  tree node is also not certain. and I try to add a keyword `nchild` to each node, showing `nchild` child nodes. so there are `nchild` pointers (saved with `**child`) to the child nodes. And once that, `**child` and `*child` should be dynamically allocated space with no certain child nodes. So you know, this is really difficult to release these spaces(and the program below is not called `free()`). Is there a better way to solve it?
- And sometimes the program below would get the garbage characters when I output the `directory tree`, which make me really confused. while debugging it, found that is the function `ent=readdir(pDir);` has read garbage characters. But when I write another simple program to read the same directory, that goes well. I think the problem is the recursive function, but I didn't get any idea. I will be appreciated if some one can give me a idea. Thanks!

```

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tree_file_s
{
  char path[512];
  time_t date;
  char type;
  long size;
  int nchild;

  struct tree_file_s **child;
} tree_file_t;

int dir_child_len(const char *dir)
{
  int nchild = 0;
  DIR *pDir;
  struct dirent *ent;

  pDir = opendir(dir);
  while((ent=readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
  {
    if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")==0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")==0) 
    {
      continue; 
    }
    nchild++;
  }

  return nchild;
}

void tree_create(tree_file_t *tft, const char *dir)
{
  int nchild; // the tft has n child
  DIR *pDir;
  struct dirent *ent; // the directory dir dirent info
  struct stat file_stat; // the new file's stat info

  stat(dir, &file_stat);
  nchild = dir_child_len(dir);
  pDir = opendir(dir);

  // Initialize the parent
  //tft->path = calloc(1, strlen(dir)+1);
  strcpy(tft->path, dir);
  tft->date = file_stat.st_mtime;
  tft->type = 'D';
  tft->size = file_stat.st_size;
  tft->nchild = nchild;
  tft->child = calloc(1, nchild);

  nchild = 0;
   while ((ent=readdir(pDir)) != NULL) 
   {
      if (ent->d_type & DT_DIR) 
      {
         if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")==0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")==0) 
         {
           continue; 
         }
         tree_file_t *new_dir = calloc(1, sizeof(tree_file_t));
         tft->child[nchild] = new_dir;

         char *new_path = calloc(1, strlen(dir)+strlen(ent->d_name)+1);
         sprintf(new_path, "%s/%s", dir, ent->d_name);
         tree_create(new_dir, new_path);
         free(new_path);
      } else {
        tree_file_t *new_file = calloc(1, sizeof(tree_file_t));
        char *new_path = calloc(1, strlen(dir)+strlen(ent->d_name)+1);
        // new_file->path = calloc(1, strlen(dir)+strlen(ent->d_name)+1);
        sprintf(new_path, "%s/%s", dir, ent->d_name);
        stat(new_path, &file_stat);
        strcpy(new_file->path, new_path);
        free(new_path);
        new_file->date = file_stat.st_mtime;
        new_file->type = 'F';
        new_file->size = file_stat.st_size;
        new_file->nchild = 0;
        new_file->child = 0;

        tft->child[nchild] = new_file;
      }
      //free(new_path);
      //new_path = 0;
      nchild++;
   }
}

void display_tree(tree_file_t *tft)
{
  int nchild, i;

  nchild = tft->nchild;

  printf("%c: %s\n", tft->type, tft->path);

  for(i = 0; i < nchild; i++)
  {
    if(tft->child[i]->type == 'F')
    {
      printf("%c: %s\n",  tft->child[i]->type, tft->child[i]->path);
    } else {
      display_tree(tft->child[i]);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: a.out dir\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  char dir[512];
  strcpy(dir, argv[1]);
  tree_file_t *tft = calloc(1, sizeof(tree_file_t));
  tree_create(tft, dir);
  display_tree(tft);

  return 0;
}
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate space for `new_path` you need to add 2 (one for the slash, one for the null terminator). And you never close the directories you open (use closedir()).

An even more serious error is this line:

```
tft->child = calloc(1, nchild);
```

which only allocates nchild bytes, not enough to hold nchild pointers! Try:

```
tft->child = calloc(nchild, sizeof(*tft->child));
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer. But when i try to modify these two places. `corrupted double-linked list:` happens at the `closedir(pDir);`

Comment: @xuefu That's indicative of a corrupted heap. I noticed another error (probably the cause of this). See the edit above.

Comment: Should not it be `calloc(nchild, sizeof(struct tree_file_s *))` (one star).  Maybe better `calloc(nchild, sizeof(* tft->child))`.

Comment: @chux is there any way to `free()` all the allocated spaces?

Comment: @xuefu: yes — you chase down every allocation you made and free any dependent allocations, then free the allocated space.  It requires some care.  For every allocation you make, work out where the corresponding `free()` occurs.